# Does this create some kind of perpetual loop? PHP wont execute properly

Tags: php, html, http, post

Does this create some kind of perpetual loop or something? I've tried posting data, and the page simply won't load, the page containing the form simply keeps "loading" on form submission.

```
for($i = 1; $i = 5; $i++) {
    $country[$i] = $_POST['country_'.$i];
    $redirect[$i] = $_POST['redirect_'.$i];
}

var_dump($country);
var_dump($redirect);
```

Here's my form;

```
<form action="query.php" method="post" id="geoui">
<div id="input1" class="clonedInput">
<select name="country_1" class="px460s">
<option selected="selected" value="auto">Choose country to set rule for..</option>
<option>United Kingdom</option>
<option>Canada</option>
</select>
<input name="redirect_1" type="text" class="px460" value="http://">
<div class="break"></div>
</div><div id="input2" class="clonedInput">
<select name="country_2" class="px460s">
<option selected="selected" value="auto">Choose country to set rule for..</option>
<option>United Kingdom</option>
<option>Canada</option>
</select>
<input name="redirect_2" type="text" class="px460" value="http://">
<div class="break"></div>
</div><div id="input3" class="clonedInput">
<select name="country_3" class="px460s">
<option selected="selected" value="auto">Choose country to set rule for..</option>
<option>United Kingdom</option>
<option>Canada</option>
</select>
<input name="redirect_3" type="text" class="px460" value="http://">
<div class="break"></div>
</div><div id="input4" class="clonedInput">
<select name="country_4" class="px460s">
<option selected="selected" value="auto">Choose country to set rule for..</option>
<option>United Kingdom</option>
<option>Canada</option>
</select>
<input name="redirect_4" type="text" class="px460" value="http://">
<div class="break"></div>
</div><div id="input5" class="clonedInput">
<select name="country_5" class="px460s">
<option selected="selected" value="auto">Choose country to set rule for..</option>
<option>United Kingdom</option>
<option>Canada</option>
</select>
<input name="redirect_5" type="text" class="px460" value="http://">
<div class="break"></div>
</div>
</form>
```

Any advice or answers would be greatly appreciated ;)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for($i = 1; $i = 5; $i++) {
```

You missed the `<`:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
```

BTW you could use the array syntax for form element names, so that instead of using `$_POST['country_'.$i]` to access posted data, you would do `$_POST['country'][$i]` or `$_POST[$i]['country']`:

```
<select name="query[1][country]" class="px460s">
<input name="query[1][redirect]" type="text" class="px460" value="http://">
```

Then in your PHP script:

```
foreach($_POST['query'] as $item) {
    $country = $item['country'];
    $redirect = $item['redirect'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, such a stupid mistake :(. I'll accept your answer once the timer drops.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will. $i = 5 is always true because 5 can always be assigned to $i.

Change to something like:

```
for($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $country[$i] = $_POST['country_'.$i];
    $redirect[$i] = $_POST['redirect_'.$i];
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, your reasoning is a bit flawed.  `$i = 0` is always false, even though the assignment succeeds.  The value of an assignment expression is the value being assigned -- assignments do not always evaluate as true because they succeed, they only evaluate as true when the value being assigned is truthy.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does:

```
for($i = 1; $i = 5; $i++) {
```

The middle clause (`$i = 5`) is an assignment -- it makes `$i` equal to 5, and then returns true, which is a truthy value, causing the loop to continue.  Try this:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not setting a limit (check) in your for function. It will loop. Should be like this:

```
for($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `assignment` operator to a `comparison` operator:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
```

instead of:

```
for($i = 1; $i = 5; $i++)
```